# Android Browser -Can it be set to NOT open new tabs?

Tags: browser, browser-tabs

I have an elderly friend that has an app - the app has a button that opens a website. When this person taps that button multiple times during the day a new browser tab opens every time. I can't teach this person how to close tabs, they just don't get it and at the end of a week that have 30 tabs open. Naturally the tablet slows to a crawl....

Is there a setting that prevents new tabs from being opened? Instead just using only one tab for everything?

Thanks for the help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such setting in the Android browser as far as I know. You could try using a different browser that does not have tab functionality, like [Orweb](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orweb), although that may have issues with cookies and may complain when the phone is not connected to Tor.

If that doesn't work, you could try [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) with the [Tab Killer extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-killer/); it may not work on mobile, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Advanced Settings in browser screenshot]

You might have this setting, I turn it off and it makes no difference, so it might be useless!